# Why does my python program ignore/skip some cases

Tags: python, loops, implementation

I'm trying to write a code which does the following:

- In the first line, it inputs two space-separated integers, the first presents the length of the list which will be input later, and the second presents an int, called `k`, which will be needed later on.
- In the second line, the list I talked about will be input

The expected output is what meets the following criteria:

number of **pairs** of ( i , j ), where i<j **and** ar[ i ]+ar[ j ] is **divisible** by `k`.

**Problem:** I don't know why my code ignores some pairs. I have tried it with many test cases, and it fails 90% of them, by outputting less pairs than expected. I know I am pretty close to the right result, I just don't know what I'm not doing right.

*For more precise information about what I want my code to do, kindly check this link (No signup or login needed):* https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/divisible-sum-pairs/problem

Here is my code:

```
#https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/divisible-sum-pairs/problem

samples_and_k = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
num_list = [int(y) for y in input().split()]
num_list.sort()
counter =0

for i in range(0, samples_and_k[0]-1):
    for j in range(i+1, samples_and_k[0]-1):
        if (num_list[i]+num_list[i+1]) % samples_and_k[1] == 0:
            counter += 1

print(counter)
```

Here's an example:

**Input:**

```
6 3
1 3 2 6 1 2
```

**Expected output:**
`5`

**The output of MY code:**
`3`

Comment: Please add current and expected output.

Comment: @Justlearnedit I just did it.

Comment: In your own words, when you write `for i in range(0, samples_and_k[0]-1):`, what is the reason for doing `-1`? In your own words, if you wrote for example `for i in range(0, 5):`, what values would you expect `i` to take on? Now, did you *check the documentation*? Did you *try it*? Does the way that `range` works agree with your expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you subtract 1 when using `range()`:

```
for i in range(0, samples_and_k[0]-1):
    for j in range(i+1, samples_and_k[0]-1):
        if (num_list[i]+num_list[i+1]) % samples_and_k[1] == 0:
            counter += 1
```

It should be:

```
for i in range(0, samples_and_k[0]):
    for j in range(i+1, samples_and_k[0]):
        if (num_list[i]+num_list[i+1]) % samples_and_k[1] == 0:
            counter += 1
```

It's a common misunderstanding when using `range()`, as `range()` is implemented somewhat unintuitively (in my opinion). The last number is *not* included in the range, so `list(range(0, 6))` is equal to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: Oh I see! You solved my issue, thanks a million :))